# config.action_controller.asset_host only works for dynamic assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am using the [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem to host my assets on amazon s3. I have setup the config.action_controller.asset_host to point to my s3 bucket so that it will serve my assets from s3.

However only my dynamically generated assets are being served from s3 the other static assets like images aren't being served from s3 they are just being served from the relative directory "/assets/filename.ext".

How can I get rails to use the s3 for my static assets and not just the dynamically generated assets?

Here is my production environment file:

```
config.cache_classes = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on  
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false  
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)   
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS   
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs   
config.assets.digest = true

ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'] = 'bucket'   
ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'key'   
ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'key'
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com"

config.assets.prefix = "/assets"

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

Comment: Is `config.assets.enabled = true` set as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the below in production.rb

`ActionController::Base.asset_host = "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com"`